# How to debug dependent library in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

The solution consists of 3 projects:

- C# application which depends on...
- CLR C++ library which in turn depends on...
- C++ library

I can debug first two, but not the last one ("No symbols have been loaded for this document"). I am in debug mode (all 3), pdb files were created.

The pdb files for both C++ libraries are created in `solution\debug` directory. .pdb file for CLR library is also copied to `bin\debug` directory of the C# project, but not .pdb for the last one. So I copied it there manually, but it didn't help.

So how to debug library which is dependency of the dependency?

*I restarted VS, as well as computer, I rebuilt solution too.*

Comment: "C++ library" is vague.  A static library doesn't have its own PDB, it gets merged into the PDB of the binary into it which it was linked.  Ought to be the C++/CLI assembly.  Simplest explanation is that you just forgot to turn on unmanaged debugging.  Right-click the C# project, Properties, Debug tab.  Ensure the "Enable native code debugging" option is turned on.  You can't single-step from managed to native code, breakpoint required.

Comment: @HansPassant, absoletely great, thank you. This did the trick. Could you please post this as regular answer, so I could mark it as accepted, thank you.

Comment: Same problem here. This solution worked for me too. (It took far too long to find this answer because I was expecting something more.. complicated).